semi vertical angle when the volume of a cone is maximized for a given total surface area
As in the title, when the volume of a cone (V) is maximum for a given total surface area, how to show that its semi-vertical angle is $\arcsin\left(\frac13\right)$?
I did this and i have no idea what went wrong.
Area($S$) $= πr^2 + πrl$
$$S = πr^2 + πr\sqrt{(h^2 + r^2)}$$
subjecting $h$ and simplifying
$$h = {\frac{\sqrt{S^2 - 2πSr^2}}{πr}}$$
Volume$$(V) = \frac 13  πr^2  h$$
Substituting $h$ and simplifying:
$V = \frac 13  r\sqrt{S^2 - 2πSr^2}$, $\frac{dV}{dS} = \frac{Sr - πr^3}{3\sqrt{S^2 - 2πSr^2}}$, to find minimum/maximum $dV/dS = 0,$
Then $Sr = 2πr^3$, $S=2πr^2$. but it should be in the form $πr^2 + πrl$, meaning $l=r$, but then $h,r,l$ cant' be a right angled triangle?
edit:
thankfully i think i did it, in my previous attempt i differentiated V with respect to S, which is a given "Constant", subjecting h and plugging it into the total volume we get
$$\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{S^2 r^2 -2\pi r^4 S}$$
$$\frac{dV}{dr}=\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{2S^2 r-8\pi r^3 S}$$
when $\frac{dV}{dr}=0$
$$2S^2r=8\pi r^3S$$
$$S=4\pi r^2$$
using $S=\pi r^2 + \pi rl$
$$\pi r^2 + \pi rl=4\pi r^2$$
$$\frac{r}{l}=\frac{1}{3}$$
which is the sine value of the semi vertical angle, but i saw some different answers, is this wrong?

HINT. $$h={\sqrt{A^2-2\pi Ar^2}\over\pi r}$$

You must differentiate wrt $r$, not $S$ (which is constant).

Consider the square of the volume $V$, then:
$$V^2=\frac r9(S^2-2\pi S r^2)$$
As the previous condition, $\frac{dV^2}{dr}=0$ needs to be set true as well. You considered differentiation against $S$, but $S$ is a constant, so the differentiation needs to be against $r$ and therefore, after differentiation, we get:
$$S=4\pi r^2$$
Plugging this value back in the equation of the height, we get:
$$h=\frac{\sqrt{16\pi^2 r^4-8\pi^2 r^4}}{\pi r}=\sqrt 8r$$
Therefore, the angle is:
$$
\theta=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+h^2}}\right)=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1+8}}\right)=\sin^{-1}\frac 13
$$

HINTS:
The method of optimization by Euler-Lagrange thm of the calculus of variations is very powerful. Leaves us in no doubt Lagrange's boasting about the true efficacy of his own methods!
Maximizing area, subjected to volume constraint, without constants:
$$ S= r \sqrt{r^2+h^2},~V=r^2 h $$
$$ \dfrac{\dfrac{\partial S }{\partial r}}{\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial h}}=  \dfrac{\dfrac{\partial V }{\partial r}}{\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial h}} $$
$$ \dfrac{  \sqrt{r^2+h^2} +r \dfrac{r}{ \sqrt{r^2+h^2}}}{r \dfrac{h}{\sqrt{r^2+h^2}}}=  \dfrac{2r}{h} $$
Simplifying,
$$ \frac{r}{h}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2},~ \frac{r}{l}=\frac{1}{\sqrt3} ;$$
i.e, $r/l$ ratio is same as the side/long diagonal length ratio of a unit cube.
